# Make Bootstrap's "Table" "Table-Hover" highlight beyond left side of bottom border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table using Bootstrap's "table" and "table-hover" classes

The thumbnail image must align flush with the left side of the bottom border, as pictured here:  (Sorry for the awkward image- I have to increase my StackOverFlow rep to post images).

When the mouse hovers over a row, activating the table-hover class, the blue highlight effect should be flush with the right side of the bottom border, but extend about 20px past the left side of bottom border.

Actually you will need to view the 2 images here in my public drop box (not enough reputation points to post two links) [Click here to view images](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yjpv7b1pz93c878/AABw9VMoo5OW7hGWrtZuc8OVa?dl=0)

Please see the following JSFiddle for my efforts thus far: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/willrichardson/L2ugrhpf/)

Thanks very much for any help that can be offered!

The HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

```
<div class="col-sm-10" id="Table">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <!-- <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead> -->

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <img class="pull-left" id="thumbnail" src="http://a.abcnews.com/images/Technology/ht_new_planet_lpl_120718_wmain.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;">
                        <div id="searchResultHeading">                          
                            <h5>Heading Black then white on row hover</h5>
                        </div>                      
                            <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                            <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> <br>
                            <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> &nbsp;  &nbsp; 
                        <div class="pull-right table-hover" id="downloadButton">
                            <a href="#"> 
                                <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <img class="pull-left" id="thumbnail" src="http://a.abcnews.com/images/Technology/ht_new_planet_lpl_120718_wmain.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;">
                        <div id="searchResultHeading">                          
                            <h5>Heading Black then white on row hover</h5>
                        </div>                      
                            <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                            <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> <br>
                            <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> &nbsp;  &nbsp; 
                        <div class="pull-right table-hover" id="downloadButton">
                            <a href="#"> 
                                <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <img class="pull-left" id="thumbnail" src="http://a.abcnews.com/images/Technology/ht_new_planet_lpl_120718_wmain.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;">
                        <div id="searchResultHeading">                          
                            <h5>Heading Black then white on row hover</h5>
                        </div>                      
                            <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                            <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> <br>
                            <span>some info grey then white on hover</span> &nbsp;  &nbsp; 
                        <div class="pull-right table-hover" id="downloadButton">
                            <a href="#"> 
                                <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
a {
    color: #22c7fa;
}

#thumbnail {
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:5px;
}

.table.table-hover > tbody > tr > td:hover {
    background-color: #22c7fa;
    color: #fff;
}
.table.table-hover > tbody > tr > td > i {
    color: #inherit;
}
.table.table-hover > tbody > tr > td > div > a {
    color: inherit;
}
#downloadButton > a{
    color:inherit;
}

#table > table {
    margin-left: 97px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: auto; 
}
/*Make all text in the search results grey*/
#Table > table > tbody > tr > td {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    color: #919191;
}
/*Make the headings in the search results black*/
#searchResultHeading {
    color:#323333;
}
/*Make all text in the search results turn white on hover*/
#Table > table > tbody > tr > td:hover {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
#Table > table > tbody > tr > td:hover h5 {
    color: #fff;
}
/* Indent the search results details */
#Table > table > tbody > tr > td > div > span {
    padding-left: 6px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove those !important flags in the CSS, it ruined the specifities (the parent id should be sufficient to gain more specifity if that's your purpose). Then you'll want to add this rule for it:

```
#Table .table.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td:first-child{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

and maybe add a little transition to it:

```
.table.table-hover > tbody > tr > td{
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L2ugrhpf/1/

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to respond. The code changes you suggested definitely looks good and clean.  I now see this wasn't clear in my post, but I have been asked to make those thumbnails thumbnails remain aligned, but still have the blue somehow expand about 20px over to the left. Do you think this is possible with CSS?

Comment: If that's the case, you can easily achieve it by simply adding a left padding to the thumbnail container:

    #Table .table.table-hover > tbody > tr > td:first-child > div{
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

https://jsfiddle.net/L2ugrhpf/2/

Comment: @HeriHeheSetiawan.That solution does look good, though I was asked to align that thumbnail right up to the left edge of the bottom border, and somehow make the highlighting stick out a further 20px to the left. I am too inexperienced to declare this as not possible with Bootstrap and CSS alone. Would you say that this is not possible with Bootstrap and CSS alone?  Thanks again for all of your time spent on this.